# Raising a Negative Double to a Fraction with/without Parentheses?

Tags: r

I came across some interesting behavior in R and I am wondering if someone can shed some light on this.

When raising a negative decimal number to a fraction power, I get different results if parentheses are placed around the negative decimal. I know the parentheses aren't needed for this calculation, but I am curious as to what is going on behind the scenes. See the following example.

```
> -1.1 ^ (1/2)
[1] -1.048809
```

vs.

```
> (-1.1) ^ (1/2)
[1] NaN
```

I would expect the output given in the second case, since this is equivalent to the following:

```
> sqrt(-1.1)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In sqrt(-1.1) : NaNs produced
```

For the first case, is R just taking the square root of the positive decimal and then tacking on a negative? When evaluating numeric expressions, does R evaluate powers before signs? In what situations would this be useful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exponentiation has a high precendence than negation.  Hence what you see.  More details [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html).

Comment: The parenthesis are needed. The unary `-` operator has a lower precedence than the `^` operator. The R parser sees the negative sign as an operator in this case rather than a sign indicator.